# use jquery in processmaker 3.1 pages and plugins

Tags: jquery, processmaker

I'm using processmaker 3.1 and wanna to hint with jquery like a tutorial:
for example in first visit a script hint about plugins.
but jquery not load completely and I can't use $(...).
when I include jquery in firebug:

```
  include('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'); 
jquery-latest.min.js properly included.
TypeError: m.isArray is not a function
```

when u use dynaforms in processmaker 3.1 it loads jquery and no extjs and maborak js apear in iframe contents.
now I wanna to exclude maborak or use jquery with maborak included. 
a question about ajax in processmaker  [Ajaxing in Processmaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037085/jquery-ajaxing-in-processmaker) give a solution to use $.conflict but firebug said:

```
$.noConflict();
TypeError: $.noConflict is not a function
$.noConflict();
```

is there anybody help me?

Comment: Hamid can you please explain a little bit more what you are trying to do? Are you creating a plugin or trying to write javascript within a dynaform?

Comment: I'm trying to use jquery at the login page of processmaker. because I don't know m,aborak.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible. ProcessMaker is currently working on a new UI that does not have maborak, but it is still a bit far out..

I don't know your exact use case, but you will probably be best served creating your own application with jquery or w/e front end framework that you want and simply connect to ProcessMaker using the REST API.

Comment: can u give me an example of using rest api in processmaker?

Answer (score 0):

```
*************************************************************************
To Create a Plugin in the in Windows for Processmaker
-----------------------------------------------------
****************************************************************************
Step :1
============
Main Steps to Plugins can not be created on Windows servers, because Windows does not support symbolic links; however, there is an experimental script for Windows servers available at <INSTALL-DIRECTORY>/workflow/engine/gulliver-win.bat which can be tested. .
http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/Plugin_Development

C:\Bitnami\processmaker-3.1-1\apps\processmaker\htdocs\workflow\engine>gulliver-win.bat new-plugin deleteCases

using DSN Connection
The plugin deleteCases exists in this file C:\Bitnami\processmaker-3.1-1\apps\pr
ocessmaker\htdocs\workflow\engine\plugins\deleteCases\class.deleteCases.php
**************************************************************************
Step :2
============
Do you want to create a new plugin? [Y/n]y

creating plugin directory C:\Bitnami\processmaker-3.1-1\apps\processmaker\plugin
s\deleteCases

saved 387 bytes in file deleteCases\setup.xml [pluginSetup.xml]
saved 183 bytes in file deleteCases\messageShow.xml [pluginMessageShow.xml]
saved 3056 bytes in file deleteCases\config\schema.xml [pluginSchema.xml]
saved 2067 bytes in file deleteCases\config\propel.ini [pluginPropel.ini]
saved 2061 bytes in file deleteCases\config\propel.mysql.ini [pluginPropel.mysql
.ini]
**************************************************************************
Step :3
============
Change system logo [y/N]y

saved 750 bytes in file public_html\deleteCases.png [deleteCases.png]
Create an example Page [Y/n]y
saved 151 bytes in file deleteCases\menudeleteCases.php [pluginMenu]
saved 932 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication.php [pluginApplicatio
n.php]
saved 45 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication.html [pluginApplicatio
n.html]
saved 6518 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication.js [pluginApplicatio
n.js]
saved 1519 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplicationAjax.php [pluginAppli
cationAjax.php]
**************************************************************************
Step :4
============
Create new option in the menu of cases [Y/n]y

saved 2384 bytes in file deleteCases\menuCasesdeleteCases.php [pluginMenuCases]
saved 547 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication2.php [pluginApplicati
on2.php]
saved 45 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication2.html [pluginApplicati
on2.html]
saved 7599 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication2.js [pluginApplicati
on2.js]
saved 547 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication3.php [pluginApplicati
on3.php]
saved 45 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication3.html [pluginApplicati
on3.html]
saved 565 bytes in file deleteCases\deleteCasesApplication3.js [pluginApplicatio
n3.js]
**************************************************************************
Step :5
============
Create the Role 'PROCESSMAKER_DELETECASES' and
       the Permission 'PM_DELETECASES' [y/N]y
**************************************************************************
Step :6
============       
Create a Redirect Login for the Role 'PROCESSMAKER_DELETECASES' [y/N]y
**************************************************************************
Step :7
============
Create external step for Processmaker [y/N]y

saved 1042 bytes in file deleteCases\stepdeleteCasesApplication.php [pluginStepA
pplication.php]
saved 45 bytes in file deleteCases\stepdeleteCasesApplication.html [pluginStepAp
plication.html]
saved 2707 bytes in file deleteCases\stepdeleteCasesApplication.js [pluginStepAp
plication.js]
saved 740 bytes in file deleteCases\stepdeleteCasesApplicationAjax.php [pluginSt
epApplicationAjax.php]
**************************************************************************
Step :8
============
Create an element for the Processmaker Dashboards [y/N]y

saved 3702 bytes in file deleteCases\classes\class.dashletdeleteCases.php [plugi
nDashletClass.php]
saved 1788 bytes in file pluginDashlet.html
**************************************************************************
Step :9
============
Create a PmFunction Class for extending Processmaker [y/N]y

saved 484 bytes in file deleteCases\classes\class.pmFunctions.php [class.pmFunct
ions.php]
saved 3089 bytes in file deleteCases.php [pluginMainFile]
saved 384 bytes in file deleteCases\class.deleteCases.php [pluginClass]
**************************************************************************
Step :10
============`enter code here`
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\Bitnami\processmaker-3.1-1\apps\processmaker\htdocs\workflow\engine>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to adding a Javascript/CSS file to ProcessMaker from within a plugin.

In order to correctly include the Javascript file, you will need to use the following path structure:

Ref: 
http://processmakerblog.com/processmaker/plugin-tips-tricks-including-javascripts-and-css-files/